# make a list of invited friends in a facebook event with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook

Hello I made an event on FB and I cannot invite more than 500 friends, so I want to open a second event to invite the last part.

I didn't invite friends following the alphabet, so now I need a script to list all the names of the not invited friends. I thought to go on the event open the list of the invited friends, scroll until end, open firebug in firefox to look at the code, make my script and use it in the console. My problem is that I don't know how to grab the text names inside the subclass tag `data-reactid`.

I have many classes like this:

```
<span class="_2akq _1box" data-reactid=".10h.2.0.0.0.0:0:1:$100001479193047.0.0.$2.$text.0.0">
   <span data-reactid=".10h.2.0.0.0.0:0:1:$100001479193047.0.0.$2.$text.0.0.0">Ele Mastro</span>
</span>
```

I try to list the names on the console, but I can only list the code. How to look inside a custom subclass like `data-reactid`. Am I obligated to use Facebook API?

I tried this code

```
var names-array = null;

var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('_2akq _1box');

for(var i=0;i<inputs.length;i++){

  var name = inputs[i].getElementsByTagName('span')[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;

  if(name != null){
    names-array.push(name);
  }

}

for (index = 0; index < names-array.length; index++) {
  console.log(names-array[index]);
}
```

but it give me this: `SyntaxError: missing ; before statement`

Comment: Please check your html, you are missing a closing </span> tag

Comment: done. Now there are all the tags... I hope :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `innerHtml` (or `innerText`)

Your Js should look like:

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('_2akq _1box');
for(var i=0; i<inputs.length;i++){ 
    console.log(inputs[i].getElementsByTagName('span')[0].innerHTML) ;
}
```

Or simply:

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('_2akq _1box');
for(var i=0; i<inputs.length;i++){ 
    console.log(inputs[i].innerText) ;
}
```

Comment: It works, but I still have usefulness code. For each name console show

<span data-reactid=".10h.2.0.0.0.0:0:1:$1318796733.0.0.$2.$text.0.0.0">Guido Palmirani</span>
Guido Palmirani 

In this case I need only "Guido Palmirani"

Comment: Answer updated according to updated code in question.

Comment: can you tell me whi I have -1 vote and they block me?

Comment: -1 in the question means that somebody downvoted it for some reason. Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/tour and here: http://stackoverflow.com/help to understand better how SO works